# Error: No match for 'operator[]'

Tags: c++

I create a class called ArrayCreator to dynamically allocate a 2D array. However when I run the main.cpp to output a specific element of the 2D array, compiler shows the following error message:

> error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'ArrayCreator' and 'int')

Please see the following code for details:

```
main.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "arraycreator.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ArrayCreator arr;
    arr.initArray();
    cout<<arr[4][5]<<endl;
    return 0;
}

---------------------------------------------------------

Header File:

#ifndef ARRAYCREATOR_H
#define ARRAYCREATOR_H
#define row 4
#define col 10

class ArrayCreator
{
    int** arr;
public:
    ArrayCreator();
    void initArray();
    ~ArrayCreator();
};

#endif // ARRAYCREATOR_H

---------------------------------------------------------

Implementation File:

#include "arraycreator.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

ArrayCreator::ArrayCreator(){
    arr=new int*[row];
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
        arr[i]=new int[col];
    }
}

ArrayCreator::~ArrayCreator(){
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
        delete [] arr[i];
        arr[i]=NULL;
    }
    delete [] arr;
    arr=NULL;
}

void ArrayCreator::initArray(){
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            arr[i][j]=i*j;
        }
    }
}
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You haven't defined `operator[](int)` for your `ArrayCreator` class.

Comment: Do you mean when I create an object of the ArrayCreator class, I cannot treat this object as a normal 2D array? In order to access any specific element of this 2D array, I need to define another function operator[](int)?

Comment: @yangfeiyun, that's exactly right.

Comment: if (remove("qt related text")) std::cout << "operator [](int) is not defined" << std::endl;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either move member `arr` in public and use it like: `arr.arr[1][1]` or define `operator[](int)` for ArrayCreator:

```
int* operator[](int index)
{
  return arr[index];
}
```